# HashMap in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am attempting to add keys/values into a HashMap using Spring, shown below:

```
<bean id="genPhrase" class="com.WheelOfFortune.Client.generatePhrase">
    <property name="WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne">
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="Object Oriented Design" value-ref="Process of planning a system of interacting objects for the purpose of solving a software problem, It is one approach to software design." />
            <entry key="Hardware devices" value-ref="Collection of physical elements that comprise a computer system." />
            <entry key="Operating System" value-ref="A set of programs that manage computer hardware resources and provide common services for application software." />
            <entry key="while statement" value-ref="A control flow statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given boolean condition." />
            <entry key="printf statement" value-ref="Refers to a control parameter used by a class of functions typically associated with some types of programming languages." />
            <entry key="Internet Service Provider" value-ref="An organization that provides access to the Internet." />
            <entry key="round robin" value-ref="Used to describe a document signed by multiple parties in a circle to make it more difficult to determine the order in which it was signed, thus preventing a ringleader from being identified." />
            <entry key="Internet Protocol" value-ref="Principal communications protocol used for relaying datagrams (also known as network packets) across an internetwork using the Internet Protocol Suite." />
        </util:map>
```

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong but when I run the code, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genPhrase' defined in file [/home/ryan/workspace/WheelOfFortuneSpring/generatePhrase.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'util:map#a6d006c' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util:map#a6d006c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'Process of planning a system of interacting objects for the purpose of solving a software problem, It is one approach to software design.' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [Object Oriented Design], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Process of planning a system of interacting objects for the purpose of solving a software problem, It is one approach to software design.' is defined
```

And finally my code:

```
public class generatePhrase implements generatePhraseInterface {
    public void readPhrase() {
        for (String key : WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne.keySet())
        {
            System.out.print(key + " : ");
        }
    }
    private Map<String,String> WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne;

    public void setWordsAndPhrasesLevelOne(Map<String,String> WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne)
    {
        this.WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne = WordsAndPhrasesLevelOne;
    }
```

Can someone advise what could be causing this exception?

Comment: Perhaps that should be `value=. . .` rather than `value-ref=. . .`. Doesn't value-ref refer to a reference to another bean?

Comment: I am not sure, I was following an example with a book about Spring. Let me give that a shot though

Comment: Good call man!! Thanks for that!!, Can you add that as an answer

Comment: Not a problem; and got that posted for anyone else that runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value-ref` attribute is used to refer to a reference to another bean. Instead, use `value=. . .` in your entries like so.

```
        <entry key="Object Oriented Design" value="Process of planning a system of interacting objects for the purpose of solving a software problem, It is one approach to software design." />
```

The giveaway here was the last bit of your error message:

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'Process of planning a system of interacting objects for the purpose of solving a software problem, It is one approach to software design.' while setting bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [Object Oriented Design], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Process of planning a system of interacting objects for the purpose of solving a software problem, It is one approach to software design.' is defined